# BlogEngine Integration Problem

Tags: blogengine.net

I have a running application in which client wants to implement BlogEngine, I have done almost but in the existing application there are also a registration, so now i want that when a user registration at my application that particular user be able to login in blogEngine.
I am using sql database and set all the settings in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Abhisheks, It sounds like you want to use the same user system as your existing web application. What you need to do is configure your authentication provider for BE.net to use the same user system as your existing app. You can either roll your own provider via code, or if your existing app is using the standard .net auth provider, then you should be able to just piggy-back off of that by configuring BE to use that via your web.config file.

Comment: Yes, i have to implement it into a developed application thats why i am facing this problem.